# How can i use Laravel relationships to get the value i want?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, model-view-controller, eloquent

[image]

As you see on the UML diagram, one or more `users` can be in charge of one `project` thats why i had to create `user_projects` table.

my situation i need create a controller that get a request that contain the `project_id` and return all the `users` that are in charge of that `project`.

My controller:

```
public function getUsers(Request $request){
 $users_project = UserProject::where('project_id', $request->project_id)->get();
 dd($users_project);
}
```

i managed to send the request with the `project_id` and get the rows from `user_projects` table that has the same `project_id` on the variant `$users_poject`, i am stuck now xD...

is it possible to do the task using `laravel relationships`?
hope someone can help finish this controller.

Comment: Another post that defines a Model for the Pivot Table... Generally, you don't do that in Laravel; you have a `User` model, a `Project` model and two `belongsToMany()` relationships. Please read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many, specifically https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure.

Comment: Rename the table `user_projects` to `project_user` as well as defining the `belongsToMany` relationship between `user` and `project` (on both models) and you can simply use `$user->projects` or `$project->users`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Althrough renaming the table is right, it is worth mentioning it is just a Laravel convention that could be bypassed by providing the name to the relationship declaration.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you guys for mentioning to me the Many To Many Relationships, i just knew about it now, and i call my self a laravel developer... lmao xD.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what about creating a `Task` ? do you recommend the same thing ?